# separate peaks from each other equidistantly

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have text file which contains for example five columns of data. Here is an example data from the text file-

```
   715.10685    -0.006153   -0.004829   -0.002161   0.000994    0.004024
   715.589053   0.000344    0.001608    0.004192    0.007262    0.010277
   716.071255   0.009477    0.010658    0.013193    0.016265    0.019321
   716.553458   0.021954    0.023053    0.025522    0.02855     0.031579
   717.035661   0.03933     0.040322    0.042648    0.045625    0.048713
   717.517864   0.065858    0.066748    0.068937    0.071936    0.075013
   718.000067   0.105093    0.105611    0.107231    0.109831    0.112457
   718.48227    0.159793    0.159685    0.160404    0.162183    0.16411
   718.964473   0.227552    0.226183    0.22505     0.224954    0.224974
   719.446675   0.280709    0.277399    0.273711    0.271167    0.268747
   719.928878   0.287966    0.284241    0.280152    0.277131    0.274246
   720.411081   0.2579      0.255127    0.252152    0.249984    0.24799
   720.893284   0.217396    0.215636    0.214007    0.213105    0.21248
   721.375487   0.183229    0.182397    0.182068    0.182365    0.182748
   721.85769    0.156936    0.156647    0.157027    0.157882    0.158674
   722.339893   0.13635     0.136406    0.137233    0.138479    0.139685
   722.822096   0.120752    0.121058    0.122156    0.123668    0.125183
   723.304298   0.107352    0.107843    0.109138    0.110859    0.112598
   723.786501   0.095212    0.0959      0.097439    0.099493    0.101428
   724.268704   0.085383    0.086165    0.08792     0.090225    0.092336
   724.750907   0.0776      0.078475    0.080518    0.083035    0.085425
   725.23311    0.070816    0.071864    0.074134    0.076913    0.07958
   725.715313   0.065264    0.066499    0.068969    0.072023    0.074953
   726.197516   0.06251     0.063919    0.06673     0.070063    0.073333
   726.679718   0.062564    0.064118    0.067235    0.07086     0.074526
   727.161921   0.064957    0.066703    0.070112    0.074137    0.078255
   727.644124   0.071889    0.073893    0.07768     0.082185    0.086759
   728.126327   0.084432    0.086715    0.090869    0.095897    0.100956
   728.60853    0.102835    0.105454    0.110048    0.115624    0.121192
   729.090733   0.129785    0.132514    0.137395    0.143102    0.148829
   729.572936   0.166336    0.168793    0.173371    0.178551    0.183697
   730.055139   0.209726    0.211157    0.214009    0.217215    0.220028
```

I have the following script which can read the text file and plot data accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.genfromtxt('peak.txt', dtype = float)

a = [row[0] for row in data]
b = [row[1] for row in data]
c = [row[2] for row in data]
d = [row[3] for row in data]
e = [row[4] for row in data]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(a,b,a,c,a,d,a,e)

plt.show()
```

It generates four plots which are on top of each other. I would like to separate them from each other equidistantly so that they can be clearly visible. One plausible way perhaps, it can look for the minima in all plots and add a certain increment so that the plots are separated equidistantly. Probably, there might be some other ways. I am not sure how I can accomplish this in python. Could someone please help me a bit. Thank you.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what you mean by "separate"?

Comment: lets say, if I can add a certain increment like 0.1 to b, 0.2 to c, 0.4 to d etc. for all the columns I have (around 20-30) and plot them in one axis, in that case all the lines are visible and separated and small difference in peak position can be be detected.

Comment: So you mean you want to add a vertical shift to separate the lines?

Comment: yes, that is true. And as I have lot of columns it would be nice if I can do it in a way so that I don't have to manually write 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ... increment in all the columns.

Comment: The eeg example(s) on the matplotlib gallery probably suit this use case well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to the list comprehensions since you read in the data as a NumPy array. Slice it accordingly and things will be easier.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.genfromtxt('peak.txt', dtype = float)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(1, data.shape[1]):
    y = data[..., i] + 0.1*i 
    ax.plot(data[..., 0], y)

plt.show()
```

So `data[..., 0]` is the same as `np.array(a)` and `data[..., 1]` is the same as `np.array(b)` for the `a` and `b` in your sample code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why don'y tou simply create a different subplot for each graph and stack them vertically?

```
x = data[:, 0]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(data.shape[1]-1, 1, sharex=True)
axes = (axes,) if n == 1 else axes
for j, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.plot(x, data[:, j+1])
```